# Отложенный рендер Razor во View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, server-side-rendering

Прошу прощения, если неккоректно описал вопрос, однако, не знаю как назвать иначе. Проблема в следующем. Есть динамические view которые собираются внутри метода index контроллера homeController. View собирается на основе модели, со string'выми полями description, title. Собственно, в метод передается id, затем метод формирует модель - загружая из базы нужную комбинацию title,description (по id) и возвращает View(model). Title и description - код html разметки. Если я в description попытаюсь запихнуть razor выражение (например @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) то при рендере оно не транслируется в html и подставляет нужные строки в зависимости от условного оператора а выводится как есть, т.е @if (User..), как тут можно срендерить razor?

Comment: то есть говоря простым языком, вы хотите в БД хранить код представления, который потом надо отрендерить?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: [собственно вот решение](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35913730/1216425) вроде. Но надо понимать, что такие вставки кода будут постоянно компилироваться, что замедлит генерацию страницы, поэтому по хорошему надо хранить некую скомпилированную версию шаблона, как это происходит для обычных представлений.